# How to temporarily turn off "snap-to" (anything) in Delphi IDE /visual designer (D2007)

Tags: delphi, ide

Every once in a while this drives me crazy: I want to move a control to some precise location, WITHOUT *any* kind of "snapping" -- snap-to-grid, snap-to-guidelines, snap-to-border, etc... and Delphi won't let me. Is there a key combination that one can use while dragging to temporarily turn off any and all "snapping"?  I seem to recall it being available in D6, but can't for the life of me find a similar combination in D2007, short of going into Tools -> Options, etc... (which kind of defeats the purpose).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Delphi 2009 CodeGear has changed the behavior of ALT+Move to also disable the designer guide lines. But in Delphi 2007 this feature can't be turned off without an external tool.

On of those tools (and I think the only that can do this) is the [DDevExtensions 1.6 IDE plugin](http://andy.jgknet.de/blog/?page_id=10) that adds this ability to ALT+Move for Delphi 2007.

Answer (score 10):

Drag with the **Alt** key down to disable snapping to the grid. Snapping to objects will remain in effect. You can use **Ctrl** with the arrow keys to move one pixel at a time. You can also type the desired coordinates into the Object Inspector.

Comment: Thanks. I did finally find that Ctrl = Arrow Keys thing -- very helpful. (It also appears that Shift + Arrow Keys does the same thing for width/height).  SO those two together have been very helpful.  

No way to temporarily turn off object-snapping though, that you know of, huH?  That is what seems to be the one that snags me. I like it on most of the time, but sometimes... it makes me kinda crabby. ;-)

Thanks Rob for taking the time to respond -- much appreciated!

Comment: Thanks Rob Kennedy and Jamo from 14 years ago! Just what I needed!